# Linking to facebook from android app using multiple signatures

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

To link to Facebook one must save an App signature hash reference. Done this, works OK. I am sure a number of people have found the issue of Apps that are marketed with Google and with Amazon that would in the normal course of events have different signatures. I am aware that it is possible to use ones own signature when publishing on Amazon to resolve this conflict. I just wondered if in fact it is possible to link to a single reference on Facebook with different signatures in any way so that I can continue to use the default Amazon signatures? Any means of using an alias ?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add several key hashes when configuring your Facebook app.

[image: Facebook Key Hashes]